# CASE on ORDER BY based on field type

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How can one execute `ORDER BY` taking into consideration the field value type?

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.test(
    data jsonb
);

TRUNCATE test;

INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('{"age":2, "name": "b"}');
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('{"age":1, "name": "cc"}');
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('{"age":4, "name": "d"}');
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('{"age":33, "name": "a"}');

-- works
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY data->>'name' ASC; 
-- works
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY (data->>'age')::numeric ASC;

-- does not work
/*
ERROR:  CASE types text and numeric cannot be matched
LINE 5:         WHEN 'number' THEN (data->>'age')::numeric
*/
SELECT data->>'name' as name, data->>'age' as age 
FROM test
ORDER BY
    CASE jsonb_typeof(data->'age')
        WHEN 'number' THEN (data->>'age')::numeric
        ELSE data->>'age'
    END
ASC;
```

*(The actual field name will be injected into the query from code)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply order by `data->'age'` or `data->'name'` without casting it in some cases.

([note the use of the `->` operator which returns a JSONB value, instead of the `->>` which always returns text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html))

[This seems to work in both cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6faf08370c8956e63e0db7795c77889):

```sql
SELECT data->>'name' as name, data->>'age' as age 
FROM test
ORDER BY data->'age' ASC;
-- name     age
-- cc         1
-- b          2
-- d          4
-- a         33

SELECT data->>'name' as name, data->>'age' as age 
FROM test
ORDER BY data->'name' ASC;
-- name     age
-- a         33
-- b          2
-- cc         1
-- d          4
```